# Online Video Platform for own servers

Tags: looking-for-a-script, linux, video

I need an application, similar to Ooyala, Vzaar, Brightcove, that manages & encodes all videos. The only difference, is that I want to host the software and content on my own servers, preferably Ubuntu, using PHP. Software does not have to be free.

The closest I've got to is Kaltura OS.

Comment: Kaltura is the ONLY self hosted package that handles everything that i'm aware of. Your only alternative to so manually install codec packages etc. and run your own player.

Answer (score 1):

Oliver makes a good point about Kaltura, they truly have a top to bottom OVP solution that can be hosted on your own servers behind your firewall called OnPrem. You can also look into LongTail Video at their BitsOnTheRun product. Our site, VidCompare.com profiles all 100 OVPs which may be helpful to you as well.

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to find if BitsOnTheRun can be purchased to run on own servers.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/newbamboo/panda.

> Panda is an open source solution for video uploading, encoding and
>   streaming.

Comment: For some reason I used to think that they only work with Ruby; but now reading, they do support PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how Panda measure up with Kaltura, i.e. difference between the two?